# Data Quality check in time series data

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, quality-control

I have time series data. The table contains date, no of orders, no of products sold, no of returns, no of walk in customers, etc. I want to create a model which takes 12 months of data as input and flags any anomaly in the next timestamps.One simple way which I can think of is to train an ARIMA model and use its confidence intervals as the upper and lower control limits. Hence if any future data point lies outside these intervals then it can be flagged as an anomaly.Note: I am using only one signal(column) at a time ie I am doing univariate time series assuming that the columns are un-correlated.

This is the scenario, type of data and a simple approach that I have. The problem statement is to create a model that does Data Quality Checks based on historical time series data.

Are there any better solution for the above problem? Note I only want to do univariate analysis ie use only one signal at at time to flag anomalies in that particular signal.
Please share any ideas that you might have. I am not sure if the above method is the best way to proceed. Any links to related research work would also be helpful.